# Python Tkinter buttons to replace labels

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a photo app where with buttons that I can press to add a filter or adjust the photo.

I'm just testing out with the Sharpen button right now.
I have

> Sharpen = img.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN).

I want it so when I press the Sharpen button, `tkpi2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)` replaces itself with `tkpi2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Sharpen)` and then have the image change to the new one. I was wondering how I can have this done? Where would I start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by keeping a reference to the labels and the original image:

```
self.original_label = Label(self.root, image=tkpi)
self.original_label.grid(row =0, column=0, padx=5,pady=5)
....
self.modified_label = Label(self.root, image=tkpi2)
self.modified_label.image = tkpi2
self.modified_label.grid(row =0, column=1, padx=5,pady=5)
```

Then, in your button handler, use `.configure()` to change the image:

```
self.modified_label.configure(image=IMAGE_HERE)
self.modified_label.image = IMAGE_HERE
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot, that helped a lot.
I'm experiencing another problem now, I'm not sure if I used the handler right or not. I edited my OP.

Comment: nvm :) i got it, I had to configure the tkpi part of my code, now the label. Thank you very much!